# Identify correct voltage/amperes from bulb brightness

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, brightness

Is there a method to establish correct voltage of an incandescent bulb by offering a voltage and measure brightness? In other words, is there a chart that tells you the brightness range of a 2.5V bulb or a 6V bulb etc. so that we can identify correct voltage range for an unknown bulb?

Comment: You could measure the brightness and increase voltage until brightness matches what's on the label. Not sure what a chart would help with though since bulbs could have different brightness.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method to establish correct voltage of an incandescent bulb by offering a voltage and measure brightness?

Not quite. Instead of brightness, you want to measure color temperature.

I am assuming it is a Tungsten filament bulb.

If you slowly add voltage (or current) to your bulb until the color temperature is between 2800 and 3000 kelvins, you will have found an operating point that both works, and is not likely to prematurely burn out the bulb.

There are devices on the market that claim to measure color temperature, but I certainly cannot vouch for the accuracy of the cheaper ones. However, you could test the accuracy of such a device by comparing it to the light from a known good bulb. A known good bulb will have a color temperature between 2700 and 3200 kelvins. Regardless of what the color temperature sensor reads, if you read a color temperature of your test bulb less than of a known good bulb, it is probably OK.

It is also claimed that one can calibrate the camera of a smart phone to measure color temperature. I also cannot vouch for how well that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that, unless you have more information about the bulb.

If you had the bulb's power or current, you could increase the voltage until it was consuming the expected power/current. Perhaps if you had the brightness in lumens or watts you could measure the brightness and do the same, but no hard and fast rule says an X volt bulb should produce Y lumens/watts.